# C# Drag and Drop From listBox

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, event-handling

I'm trying to build a simple interface that allows users to drop files into a `listBox` to add them to a process, and to drag them out to remove them. Everything is working fine, but I'd like to add one feature to make it just a tad more sophisticated.

Right now, I have the removal of the item tied to the `DragLeave` event, which means that as soon as the mouse leaves the box, the item is removed. But I'd like for users to be able to change their minds. In other words, if they realize they're dragging the wrong file out, I'd like them to be able to move the mouse back into the `listBox` and release the mouse to cancel the action. I'm thinking that means I need to be able to capture the `MouseUp` event instead of the `DragLeave` event. But that hasn't been successful so far.

Below is the code I'm currently using for removing files dragged out. How can I modify to keep the files from being removed form the list until the user lets the mouse button go?

```
private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
    { 
        return; 
    }

    int index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);
    string s = listBox1.Items[index].ToString();
    DragDropEffects dde1 = DoDragDrop(s, DragDropEffects.All);
}

private void listBox1_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lb = sender as ListBox;
    lb.Items.Remove(lb.SelectedItem);
}
```

**Edit 2013/05/16**

The comments and answers so far have been useful, but I realize my question isn't clear enough. In this case, I'm displaying a dialog separate from the parent form that is basically as big as the `listBox`. When someone drags a file out of the list, they're dragging it off the form completely. Have I backed myself into a corner by doing this? I recognize I'm making it harder than it has to be, but I'd still like to see how it would work if it's possible.

Comment: Instead of let the user remove the item by drag it outside the `ListBox`, you can make a DragDrop destination for the user to drag to in order to remove it. In that case you can move `lb.Items.Remove(lb.SelectedItem);` to the `DragDrop` event handler on that destination control.

Comment: another alternative approach is to provide an alert `messagebox` before `lb.Items.Remove(lb.SelectedItem);` to double confirm with the user.

Comment: Put a garbage can icon on your form.  Now it is clear to both your user and your code.

Comment: @HansPassant, I tried this, but I couldn't get the DragDrop events to work. I used the same event handlers as above. There was no reaction.

Comment: @Bolu, Thanks! Both good suggestions. I revised my question to clarify my goal, but this is working great as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a fairly quick hack approach to gaining the functionality you want:

```
public object lb_item = null;



private void listBox1_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lb = sender as ListBox;

    lb_item = lb.SelectedItem;
    lb.Items.Remove(lb.SelectedItem);
}

private void listBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{       
    if (lb_item != null)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(lb_item);
        lb_item = null;
    }
}


private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    lb_item = null;

    if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }                

    int index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);
    string s = listBox1.Items[index].ToString();
    DragDropEffects dde1 = DoDragDrop(s, DragDropEffects.All);      
}

private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{            
    lb_item = null;
}
```

Every time the user drags an item out of the box, it's saved temporarily until the user drops it somewhere else or mouses down on a new item in the list. 
Note the important part of this is detecting when and where the user let's go of that mouse, which is the rationale behind handling the `DragDrop` event of `Form1`, the parent of `listBox1`.

Depending on the sophistication and density of the rest of your layout, where you handle `DragDrop` could be much different for you. This is why it's kind of "hacky", but it's also quite simple. It shouldn't matter, though, where or how many times you null `lb_item` since it pertains only to that specific `ListBox`.

I suppose another way to do it would be to track the user's mouse states and act accordingly, which may be more appropriate for you if it's inconceivable to handle a lot of `DragDrop` stuff.

EDIT: If you wanted to be REAL thorough, you could enumerate through *every* control of the base form using `foreach` and programmatically append a handler for the DragDrop event to that control, then remove it when done... but that may be getting a little nutty. I'm sure someone has a better approach.

Comment: Awesome, @glace! Thanks! The global variable is a great addition and a key piece I was missing. I updated my question to clarify my goal. What do I do if I drag it off of the form?  Do I just add a `DragEnter` event handler to the form as a whole?

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure. Give it a try, mess around and see if the events get tripped. There has to be a way to do this, I'm surprised no one else has chimed in with a better solution.

Comment: Your solution allows me to drag on and off the form, as well. No changes necessary. Thanks!