# Drag and Drop on List Boxes of Objects

Tags: c#, wpf, object, drag-and-drop, listbox

I have a `List` of `Employee`. I just want to perform simple Drag and Drop. i.e. drag and remove an `Employee` from `SourceListBox` and Add that `Employee Object` in `TargetListBox`.
I am having two problems.
Removing the employee from SourceListBox gives me an exception and the value displayed in TargetListBox is not the Employee Object but the string `Drag_and_Drop.Employee`

```
       private List<Employee> emp = new List<Employee>();
 emp.Add(new Employee { EmployeeId = 1, Name = "Arslan" });
            emp.Add(new Employee { EmployeeId = 2, Name = "Talha" });

 SourceListBox.ItemsSource = emp;
            SourceListBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
            SourceListBox.SelectedValuePath = "EmployeeId";

 private void SourceListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {   

            DragDropEffects dde = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(SourceListBox, SourceListBox.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.All);

            var empi = (Employee) SourceListBox.SelectedItem;

            if(dde == DragDropEffects.All)
            {
                emp.Remove(empi);
                SourceListBox.ItemsSource = null;
                SourceListBox.ItemsSource = emp;
            }
        }

   private void TargetListBox_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.All;
            TargetListBox.Items.Add(e.Data.GetData(typeof(Employee)));
        }
```

Comment: I don't know the exact answer for your question, but if you "just want to perform simple Drag and Drop", better to use some library which make it easier. Implementing drag'n'drop yourself is the way, full of pain, bugs and big chances your solution will not have beautiful interface. For example - https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop - you can make your drag'n'drop in 3 rows of code.

Answer (score 0):

Basic example from [C# Drag and Drop From listBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591975/c-sharp-drag-and-drop-from-listbox)

```
public object lb_item = null;   

private void listBox1_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lb = sender as ListBox;

    lb_item = lb.SelectedItem;
    lb.Items.Remove(lb.SelectedItem);
}

private void listBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{       
    if (lb_item != null)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(lb_item);
        lb_item = null;
    }
}


private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    lb_item = null;

    if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }                

    int index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);
    string s = listBox1.Items[index].ToString();
    DragDropEffects dde1 = DoDragDrop(s, DragDropEffects.All);      
}

private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{            
    lb_item = null;
}
```

and for to expand knowledge http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5883/Two-ListBoxes-Drag-and-Drop-Example

Comment: not helpful as it is for WinForms, I am working in WPF and there is no such method `IndexFromPoint`